# Grails Strategy needed for handling many queries populating a GSP page

Tags: sql, grails, gsp

Please forgive if this question sounds basic... I'm basically a QA Eng. (not a dev my trade), and I'm writing tools for testing a voip framework - using Grails.  The tool I built works great, but when i got to the step of making a reports view (like a Dashboard), I feel I'm just not doing this right.

The problem is, the Dashboard page takes about 20seconds to load.  It's too slow for my stakeholder, who would like this page to load in a few seconds.

So what I'm looking for is a strategy to implement a better way to pull data into this gsp page.

How I'm doing this currently is probably the worst way possible... so I'm hoping to hear of a better way to accomplish this.  I'm looking more for a strategy or an idea of what I should research on how to better accomplish this.

The grails application basically dials phone numbers via some quartz jobs (running every 10min) to verify the phone carriers complete the calls - the app marks them as a "pass" or "fail" as well as getting a "fail count" over a period of time (i.e. the sprint number failed 1 time in 1 hour, 3 times in 6 hours, 10 times in 24 hours, etc.)

For the Dashboard controller/page, in the class I have many queries like this:

```
def proxyRowCount24Hours = ProxyScan.executeQuery("select count(id) from ProxyScan where ipProxy='xxxxxxxxxxxx' AND dateCreated >= '"+within24Hours+"'",[max: 1])[0]

 def proxyFailCount6Hours = ProxyFailCounter.executeQuery("select proxyFailCount from ProxyFailCounter where proxy='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' AND dateCreated >= '"+dateMinus6Hr+"' order by proxyFailCount desc",[max: 1])[0]
```

The Dashboard page shows data like:
the pass/fail, failures per 1 hr, failures per 6 hours, failures per 24 hr

So if I have 30 phone numbers by carrier to call: I have 30 queries to get pass/fail, 30 other queries to get failure by hour 30 queries to get failures over 6hours... 30 queries to get failure by 24hours.  So it's a lot of queries.

I return the values and in a GSP called dashboard.gsp, I pull in these returned values.

It works, but ... it's slow.  So how can I do this better?  I have a lot of queries, and I think maybe that's the first problem.

I'm using the H2 db, instead of MySQL.

Also... Should I be caching the page?  Currently the queries all run each time the Controller/page loads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you do not want to be querying the DB multiple times for each phone number.  You'd like this to have one query or certainly not separate queries for each phone number.  I'm not familiar with h2 or nor can I recall the syntax for hql but it'd be something like:

```
SELECT ipProxy, 
       sum(case when (createdDate > sysdate - 1) then 1 else 0) as countsIn24hours, 
       sum(case when (date > sysdate - 1/4) then 1 else 0) as countsIn6hours, 
       sum(case when (date > sysdate - 1/2) then 1 else 0) as countsIn12hours 
FROM ProxyFailCount 
GROUP BY ipProxy
```

Comment: Thanks Jim.  So basically I should work on making fewer trips to the db (i.e. combining the queries.)  Sounds good.  Are there any other best practices I should follow?  Is it safe to have the query fire on page refresh?

Comment: Given that you want to see changes made in hours, you might want to have your query fire every refresh.  Best practice-wise, you definitely want to make less calls to the DB, but if you want to see live changes you probably don't want to cache a lot either.  How much caching and where you cache generally depends on how volatile your data is.  Things that rarely change you can cache at the page level, things that change a lot you'll want to cache at the DB level and have a dependency that checks when changes are made.  Hope that helps